# ActionScript 3 MovieClip content scroll for Android

Tags: android, actionscript, movieclip

I need to create a vertical scroll-able movieclip (MC) for android touch device.
This MC will be on the stage. The content of the MC should be scroll-able vertically with touch (single finger).

Can anyone help please?

Comment: not sure about performance issues, as I don't own an android phone, but have a look at the [scrollRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect) property to start with.

Comment: Did you have a look at this link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871435/how-to-make-a-scrollable-ui-in-touch-flash-cs5-for-mobile-devices-primarily-ios